# Suggestions for range slider plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, range, uislider

I've seen already standart `jQuery` range slider on jQuery website, but this is not quite, what I'm looking for.

I've also found very nice range slider http://blog.egorkhmelev.com/2009/11/jquery-slider-safari-style/, but this plugin is bit buggy and hard to fix, since it was selfmade and doesn't have almost any community.

Could anyone suggest other good looking `jQuery` plugin for that purpose?

Comment: You should try to style the Jquery UI official slider. It's the best

Answer (score 0):

Check out jqPlot  (jqplot.com) with the 'draggable' plugin.  Use can set it to constraint dragging to the x-axis.

Jqplot is well tested and has very extensive functionality

Comment: Didn't find any range sliders there.